# SQL management studio: replace "\n" symbol?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to replace all the `\n` in SQL Management studio (2008) to spaces ?

I tried to do that , and :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand the Find Options, you can check the box to enable regular expressions and that will allow you to use the \n notation for new lines.